# how to join an django model object response

Tags: python, django

I have this Django/Python call:

```
Stuff = Source.object.value_list(dbtype, host)
```

What I want to do is create this string:

```
`"mssql@12.12.12.12, MySQL@23.23.23.23"`
```

I tried to peform a join: `",".join(Stuff.dbtype + " " + Stuff.host)`  and that failed miserably.

Is there a version of the `join` call that will do what I'm looking for without manually iterating through my object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `values` instead of `values_list`:

```
stuff = Source.objects.values('dbtype', 'host')
```

Then:

```
stuffs = [i['dbtype'] + '@' + i['host'] for i in stuff]
result = ', '.join(stuffs)
```

or:

```
def compose(stuff):
    return stuff['dbtype'] + '@' + stuff['host']

temp = map(compose, stuffs)
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x + ', ' + y, temp)
```

Comment: I got an error there, but it got me where I wanted when I changed `i['dbtype']` to `i.dbtype` and `i['host']` to `i.host`.  then it worked.  THanks much.  This helps.

Comment: I edited my answer, with another method without explicitly iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) return list of tuples, so you can't write Stuff.dbtype.

Secondly, [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes iterable object as parameter like list.

So you can rewrite your code like this:

```
Stuff = Source.object.values_list(dbtype, host)
result = ', '.join([dbtype + '@' + host for dbtype, host in Stuff])
```